# webm live input to HLS live output

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have ben struggling with this for quite some time; Essentially what I'm trying to do is broadcast my webcam from within the Browser to Ffmpeg on the server to convert into a .m3u8 HLS live stream. But I am having a few problems with video playback I initially thought it was [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136761/cross-origin-request-blocked-hls-url) and cross origin headers however now I am thinking its to do with the way I'm trying to encode the media.

I did a ffprobe on the input this was the response;

```
SERVER:key destination set to:1618380585-6666-863686008-4444-21
FFMPEG:Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: 
FFMPEG:N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

I am wondering if someone could help with the ffmpeg parameters; I am currently using the following;

```
    var ops=[
        '-r', '17',
        '-i','-',
        '-strict', '-2',
        '-vf', 'scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease',
        '-c:a', 'aac',
        '-ar', '48000',
        '-b:a', '128k',
        '-c:v', 'h264',
        '-profile:v', 'main',
        '-crf', '20',
        '-g', '48',
        '-keyint_min', '48',
        '-sc_threshold', '0',
        '-hls_time', '4',       
        '-hls_segment_filename', '/var/www/html/streams/segments/streamKey-date-%02d.ts',
        '-hls_base_url', '/streams/segments/',
        '/var/www/html/streams/streamKey.m3u8'
    ];
```

I have also run into other problems and I was also wondering if i needed to build ffmpeg differently; here is the current build I am running; I only wonder this becuase when i try to add the `-hls_playlist_type live` parameter I get a response of `not found`.

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

**EDIT**

I have also included an example .m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.647056,
/streams/segments/1618380585-6666-863686008-4444-21-668-00.ts
#EXTINF:2.823533,
/streams/segments/1618380585-6666-863686008-4444-21-668-01.ts
#EXTINF:5.647056,
/streams/segments/1618380585-6666-863686008-4444-21-668-02.ts
#EXTINF:0.294122,
/streams/segments/1618380585-6666-863686008-4444-21-668-03.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: `ffmpeg version 2.8.17`. From 2015. Way too old. Don't waste your time with this. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) a modern version and try again.

Comment: @llogan Thanks that actually resolved the problem along with `-re` I updated and now audio and video sync and constant connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg 2.8.17 is from 2015 and is way too old. Don't waste your time with this.

[Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) a modern version and it will work.